# how to combine list items with buttons using jquery appendTo()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

as of right now i have  my list item and my button underneath it, i want my button right next to the next of the list item. I tried using the name = but it just outputs the string version of the html for the button rather than the actual html button itself

```
  function addCheckbox(name, id) {
     var container = $('#sortable');
     var items = container.find('li');
    //name = name+ '<button type="button" id = "delete" value="delete">Delete</button>';
     $('<li /> ', { 'id': 'cb_'+id, text:''+ name }).appendTo(container);
     $('<button> ', { 'id': 'delete', value:'delete' , text:'delete' }).appendTo(container);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the button to the li

```
var li = $('<li /> ', { 'id': 'cb_'+id, text:''+ name });
li.appendTo(container);
$('<button> ', { 'id': 'delete', value:'delete' , text:'delete' }).appendTo(li);
```

Also if you are having more than one delete button, you need to make the id of the delete button unique. Use a classname that is common and just listen for the click event.

```
$(container.on("click", "button.deleteClass", function () {
    console.log(this);
    //$(this).closest("li").remove();
});
```

Comment: if i make the delete button say 'delete'+id how would i find if that button was called?